# How to remove the ul tags from the output of a radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

For my project I created a new custom field type, called RadioList. This RadioList class extends the [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. I use repeatlayout [UnorderedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I want to remove the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags from the output.

```
<ul id="formcontent_99_form_ERWGE3B247CGEERGERGER3591E9D09B15A53_field_C34534534766B3DB6FFD45454353475pure" class="coord">
<li>{I WANT TO KEEP THIS CONTENT}</li>
<li>{I WANT TO KEEP THIS CONTENT}</li>
<li>{I WANT TO KEEP THIS CONTENT}</li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know how I could realize that?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can do this with CSS:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

Now, in your case you might want to add a class to that:

```
.radio-list ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

and then in the ASPX markup:

```
CssClass="radio-list"
```

as an attribute.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to remove the ul and li tags from the output using C# code.

Comment: @Jordy, they you're going to have to override `OnRender`.

Comment: I know. Did you know how?